# Why "requests" module timeout doesn't work in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, urllib3

I want to fetch content of a URL and in cases I face `50X` HTTP error codes, retry for 10 times with 0.5 seconds delay between retries. I also want to have a 1 second timeout for my requests. To aim this goal I tried the following program:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import requests
from urllib3.util.retry import Retry
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter    

URL = "http://<DOMAIN>/Loader.aspx?ParTree=15131H&i=" # + stockid


def get_data(stockid):

    print("1")
    req_session = requests.Session()

    print("2")
    retries = Retry(total = 10, 
                    backoff_factor = 0.5,
                    status_forcelist = [500, 502, 503, 504])

    print("3")
    req_session.mount("http://", HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))

    print("4")
    page_content = req_session.get(URL + stockid, timeout=1).content

    print("5")

get_data(sys.argv[1])
```

Unfortunately it freezes for minutes after printing 4 on the screen. What is wrong?

Comment: How do you call your code? Which means: What is `sys.argv[1]`?

Comment: `id` is not used, so it is not needed...

Comment: @Manuel Sorry that was a typo. I edited the question. Thankyou.

Comment: it works fine with accessable urls. please give us the full link

Comment: @InfinityTM As the web server's behavior is not deterministic, adding such information doesn't help much. Accessible URLs are okay, the issue appears in cases which the web server doesn't answer in expected time.

Comment: ok. does my answer help you?

Comment: @InfinityTM I'm trying to reproduce the issue using Linux IPTables (dropping http requests to make client re-transmit its requests). Then I can check your answer. Thank you. I'll let you know soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a Windows User, first of all. Your `timeout` works fine. Here the `backoff_factor` creates the issue. Try:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import requests
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry # requests.packages. is not necessary
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter    

URL = "http://<DOMAIN>/Loader.aspx?ParTree=15131H&i=" # + stockid


def get_data(stockid):

    print("1")
    req_session = requests.Session()

    print("2")
    retries = Retry(total = 10, 
                    backoff_factor = 0.5,
                    status_forcelist = [500, 502, 503, 504])
    requests.packages.urllib3.util.Retry.BACKOFF_MAX = 0.5 # required
    # requests.packages. is not necessary
    # it isin't necessary you have to mount this way
    print("3")
    adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries)
    req_session.mount('http://', adapter)
    req_session.mount('https://', adapter)

    print("4")
    page_content = req_session.get(URL + stockid, timeout=1).content

    print("5")

get_data(sys.argv[1])
```

This way is also possible:

```
retries = RetryRequest(
        total=10,
        backoff_factor=0.5,
        status_forcelist=[500, 502, 503, 504],
        max_backoff=backoff_factor)
```

It is documented that, when you use the `backoff_factor`:

> It will never be longer than `Retry.BACKOFF_MAX` ( which is by default `120`).

So when you try your link, the `BACKOFF_MAX` preceeds your `backoff_factor`, which increase your execution time. Therefore, setting:

```
requests.packages.urllib3.util.Retry.BACKOFF_MAX = 0.5
```

will help you.
But this error shouldn't be raised since it defined as:

```
min(self.BACKOFF_MAX, backoff_value)
```

in:

```
urllib3.util.retry
```

Comment: Is `backoff_factor` the delay time between failed requests?

Comment: the `backoff_factor` is just like `sleep()`, It sleeps for a particular time between the retries

Comment: Ok. I din't understand why I have to change `BACKOFF_MAX`. As I understand from your quotes from the API documentation, I must have my backoff_factor less than `BACKOFF_MAX`. But why I need to change the value of `BACKOFF_MAX`?

Comment: I'll reply after I invest a little time in this

Comment: I found the answer. Please add this to your answer: The delay between retries is calculate as `{backoff factor} * (2 ** ({number of retries} - 1))` and not `backoff_factor` itself.

Comment: Ok. I will update my answer with answers to the demo

Comment: I removed my demo.

Comment: I read some of it. In config one, the the timeout is the amount of time to be used to connect to the host. Since you blocked the connections, i believe, the host returned the error in time less than the timeout.

Comment: The IPTable rule make the host to drop the packets. It doesn't return any response. All the issues are related to the backoff_factor role as you said earlier. It doesn't have a linear effect.

Comment: Sorry, I want but I can't. It's too late to undo the upvote.